# Does Eclipse run Java or Javascript?

Tags: javascript, java, eclipse

I have been learning programming language on Eclipse for around 2 months but until now, I thought Java and Javascript were the same. So I don't know which one I have been learning. Can someone tell me which one works on Eclipse?

EDIT - I found out that I have been learning Java thanks to you. Thank you all guys.

Comment: If you post some code, you can get a clear answer. Eclipse itself is plugin based and can support not only a wide variety of programming languages but even non-programming applications that want to use its UI setup.

Comment: Technically Java includes a JavaScript implementation (at least currently) `new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByExtension("js").eval("(function () {console.log('Hello, World!')})()");`

Comment: @ElliottFrisch no kidding! Which version of Java introduced this?

Comment: @CardinalSystem I think Java 5. It was available with [Rhino](https://github.com/mozilla/rhino) even earlier (and if Oracle actually removes it from base Java, I'm sure it'll still be available with Rhino).

Comment: This is exactly the question I wish that many new Stack Overflow users would ask before they start putting the wrong language tag on their first questions. Thank you! Upvoted.

Answer (score 2):

Vanilla Eclipse is only for Java. However, it can actually can be used for developing in both languages, especially given that JS does not require compiling. All you need is a plugin like [Eclipse Web Developer Tools](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-web-developer-tools-0) (see [Introducing the Eclipse Marketplace Client](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/marketplace-client-intro) for instructions on installing). There are also other Eclipse IDEs like [Eclipse CDT](https://www.eclipse.org/cdt/) that support languages like `C++` and `C#`.

Take a look at [this](https://java.com/en/download/help/java_javascript.html#:%7E:text=Key%20differences%20between%20Java%20and,code%20are%20all%20in%20text.) too.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by _"vanilla Eclipse"_, but there are different IDE packages that can be downloaded from eclipse.org, including some for Java, JavaScript, C/C++, Rust and PHP. There are two different Eclipse projects for JavaScript language support: JSDT of Eclipse Web Developer Tools (the one you mentioned) and [Eclipse Wild Web Developer](https://github.com/eclipse/wildwebdeveloper). The later one provides the [_Eclipse IDE for JavaScript and Web Developers_](https://download.eclipse.org/wildwebdeveloper/releases/latest/IDEs/).

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on [Cardinal System's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67188445/13710015), Java and Javascript are two very different languages. When it was created, it was named Javascript as a lightweight version of Java that was used on the web (in reality it is not this). Recently Javascript has been used outside of the browser, as with [NodeJS](https://nodejs.org/) and [Deno](https://deno.land/). They share some similarities (such as using `}`) but they are two very different languages.

Comment: "it was named Javascript as a lightweight version of Java..."  Well, mostly just to steal Java's popularity. +1

Comment: @CardinalSystem hahaha yup. Its name probably made it gain half of the popularity it has today.

Answer (score 1):

By all likelihood you are learning Java (not JavaScript). You are correct, they are two very different languages, and quite often confused.

**Java** If you start out by something like `public static void main(String[] args)`, then it’s Java for certain (and even if you don’t, it may still well be). Here’s a typical first program you see in Java.

```
class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello, World!"); 
    }
}
```

(Here taken from the Programiz web site.) The call to `System.out.println()` is specific to Java too.

**JavaScript** If you embed your code inside tags in HTML, then it’s JavaScript (and again, even if you don’t, is may still be JavaScript). The following JavaScript example was taken from the Tutorialspoint tutorial.

```
<html>
   <body>   
      <script language = "javascript" type = "text/javascript">
         <!--
            document.write("Hello World!")
         //-->
      </script>      
   </body>
</html>
```

**Other ways to make certain** Also your course material, tutorial or text book should say what your language is.

**Links**

- [Java Hello World Program](https://www.programiz.com/java-programming/hello-world) on Programiz
- [Javascript Tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/index.htm) on Tutorialspoint